# Converting an HDMI signal into USB-A

Tags: usb, usb-device, hdmi

I am working on a project which involves an active HDMI<-->USB-A converter. I may not be searching for the right thing, but I cannot find a circuit to perform this anywhere. I know it is possible, there are products out there that do this but I cannot find any information on how.

I cannot use USB-C for this due to unrelated complications.
Does anyone know anything about this?

Edit: I have found the actual name of the device I am looking to build, an HDMI capture card. I still can't find anything about how one is implemented, though.

Comment: A capture card is a *very* complicated thing to make. Just buy one from elgato or someone, it'll be way cheaper.

Comment: I see, alrighty

Comment: The commercial units most likely use an obscure chip that does exactly what is required and you only get the datasheet if you buy a million chips.